# get an information from an html id with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Please I need to get the date with javascript from this div:

```
<div id="popupDateFieldMin" class="dateField">2017-08-02</div>
```

here is my actual code of this part.

```
var cal = document.getElementById( 'popupDateFieldMin' );
    console.log(cal.outerHTML)
```

thanks in advance, G. B

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use innerHTML for that:

```js
    var cal = document.getElementById( 'popupDateFieldMin' );
    console.log(cal.innerHTML)
```

```html
 <div id="popupDateFieldMin" class="dateField">2017-08-02</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateValue = document.getElementById("popupDateFieldMin").value;
console.log(dateValue);
```

You can also set the value by

```
document.getElementById("popupDateFieldMin").value = "2017-08-02";
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using innerHTML property

According to MDN:

> The Element.innerHTML property sets or gets the HTML syntax describing the element's descendants. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

On return, you will get the DOM content as a String and not exclusively the text inside the div.

```
<div id="popupDateFieldMin">2017-08-02</div>
```

You will get the following result:

```
content = document.getElementById('popupDateFieldMin').innerHTML
// content = 2017-08-02
```

What happens if you change the structure of your div element ? By adding a span element for example:

```
<div id="popupDateFieldMin"><span style="color:blue">2017</span>-08-02</div>
```

innerHTML will return `<span style="color:blue">2017</span>-08-02` not `2017-08-02`.

It's fine if your div contains only text but not suitable in all cases.

### A better solution : textContent property

> Node.textContent property represents the text content of a node and its descendants.

Returns the concatenation of the textContent property value of every child node. It has better performance because the text is not parsed as HTML. Moreover, using textContent can prevent XSS attacks.

```
content = document.getElementById('popupDateFieldMin').textContent
// content = 2017-08-02
// in both cases
```

### Best practice : time element

> The HTML  element represents either a time on a 24-hour clock or a precise date in the Gregorian calendar (with optional time and timezone information).

This element is for presenting dates and times in a machine readable format, for future data processing.

```
<time id="myTime" datetime="2017-08-02">2017-08-02</time>
```

Then, to access this value :

```
document.getElementById("myTime").getAttribute("datetime");
```

Answer (score 0):

cal.textContent will give you the value of the tag after convert the value into 
date use new Date().

**Example**

```
  let dateString =cal.textContent 
  console.log(dateString ) //value 2017-08-02
  let date = new Date(dateString) //gives date object
```